# Livewire: how to emit an event to children components?

Tags: laravel-livewire

I've found from the v2 documentation on Livewire that Livewire has these ways to scope events: `$emit` will emit the event to everything, `$emitUp` will emit the event to parent components only, `$emitSelf` will emit the event only to the instance of the component that emits the event, and `$emitTo` will emit the event to a component of a specific type.

How do I emit the event to child components only?

Comment: `emitTo` is the best approach IMO **provided the child component is booted**. Just declare a listener and emit to the child component.

Comment: @mrtorks May I ask for a documentation link to read more about booting the child component?

Comment: There is no documentation as such for emitting to child component. Consider it as another component and then emitTo it. Ideally you would want something like `emitDown` however that does not exist. It might in a future release.

Comment: @mrtorks Consider a Livewire component that has a button that should open a certain modal window, which is a Livewire component. If I will `emitTo` a certain **type** of the component, then if I will have multiple components with these buttons on one page, I will trigger all modals on a page to open instead of a direct child.

Comment: What is the goal of the emit? is it to set a value? or something else

Comment: Also until the modal is rendered,(you can see the component view), the component is not booted so an emitted event is only listened to by a component that is booted irrespective of if it is defined in multiple places. with the exception of if it is hidden.

Comment: @mrtorks The goal of the emit is to pass a file blob that gets uploaded via an input type file for preprocessing in the modal window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251872/discussion-between-mrtorks-and-rusurano).